# leaflet typescript loading

Tags: typescript, leaflet

I'm trying to reproduce the simpler example of loading a map with leaflet  as shown in leaflet site but coding in typescript. I'm not using any framework like angular or react.
I've installed leaflet and types through npm.
In order to follow our guidelines the html is built at runtime adding divs etc as we need them, particularly for the map I have in the constructor of a class:

...

```
this.MapFrame = document.createElement('div');
this.MapFrame.style.height = "416px";
this.MapFrame.style.width = "616px";

this._mapArea = document.createElement('div');
this._mapArea.style.height = "400px";
this._mapArea.style.width = "600px";
this._mapArea.id = "mapid";
this.MapFrame.appendChild(this._mapArea);
```

...
and MapFrame is added to the document.

In a class's method follows:

```
this.mymap = L.map("mapid").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

that row give the 'container already initialized' error even if I have not called any of leaflet code before. If I remove the div that contains the map and put another one that will be immediately filled with a map without any call. If I try with:

```
this.mymap = L.map(this._mapArea).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

I can manage to load the map but trying to move it by dragging I'll have an Uncaught TypeError: t.classList.contains is not a function

while zooming is possible with buttons or mouse wheel.

[In a base html there's the script and css inclusion, attached there is the resulting html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLNJm.png)

Can anyone help me understanding what's going behind the scenes? Particularly I can't understand why the map is loaded even if I don't call it before and why I can't drag It.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Given the currently shared info, your issue looks strange indeed. Please could you provide a live reproduction example of your issue, for example using CodeSandbox or StackBlitz? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here is a sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-austin-keltn) and it works but mine don't. I keep receiving error when trying to grab the map or just click on it... seems I have to look better at my code but till now can't manage where to look.

Comment: Welcome! The screenshot you've included via a link towards the end of your post is too low-res to be able to zoom in and also read the text. Could you copy and paste the code from innermost `<div>` that captures all the relevant information?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The main error was a typeerror introduced by a chunck of code added for old IE versions that weren't supporting the classList property of elements.